# Hive multiple count (with and without DISTINCT) generate bad output

Tags: hive, hiveql

I tried this Hive query

```
Select id,count(distinct CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),60) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
         ,count(CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),60) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
From DB.TABLE2 GROUP BY id limit 10;
```

And it gives me smthg like:

```
111007001007633 1       1
111007001029793 1       1
111007001000521 1       11
111007001000794 1       1
111007001000273 3       13
111007001001032 1       1
111007001025874 1       4
111007001001792 1       7
111007001029181 1       1
111007001000141 16      96
```

But when I add other count:

```
 Select id,count(distinct CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),60) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
         ,count(CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),60) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
         ,count(distinct CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),15) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
         ,count(CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(m_date) BETWEEN unix_timestamp(cast(date_sub(cast('2017-02-01' as date),15) as date)) AND unix_timestamp(cast('2017-02-01' as date)) THEN m_date ELSE 0 END) 
 From DB.TABLE2 GROUP BY id limit 10;
```

It returns something bad like this:

```
 111007001010439 0       0       1       0
 111007001026963 0       0       1       0
 111007001028001 0       0       1       0
 111007001032987 0       0       1       0
 111007001048710 0       0       1       0
 111007001052415 0       0       1       0
 111007002008374 0       0       1       0
 111007003000644 0       0       1       0
 111007003002210 0       0       1       0
```

I work on hadoop cluster and I don't if it's caused by the map reduce.

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

As I answered to @pashaz comment, the first problem is the results from the two same queries (with and without distinct) which give 1 for distinct and 0 for non distinct.

The second problem is the results between the two distinct queries and the two non-distinct queries. If you check the timestamps you'll see that the first queries contains the seconds because the two firsts count occurrences between "2017-02-01" and **60 days** before, the 2nds count occurrences between "2017-02-01" and **15 days** before.

**[UPDATE]**

If I put a WHERE clause it works

```
 WHERE id="111007001007633" OR id="271011604404359" OR id="122213250512607" OR id="111007001033217"


111007001033217 0       0       0       0       0       0
122213250512607 1       3       8       14      0       0
271011604404359 12      21      26      42      5       9
111007001007633 14      19      24      34      5       5
```

The LIMIT clause seems to be the problem.

Comment: Is the second query returning those results (0,0,1,0) for every single row?  What happens if you run the second query for one of the rows that the first query returns "valid" results for, like 111007001000141?

Comment: @Andrew I don't know, I will check and give you the result ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad in provided results. In both queries present "limit 10". There no garantee that the same ID will be returned.

In first query results present "111007001007633" which absent in second query.

Comment: Check the query ! Each time the 1st is distinct, the 2nd is the same without the distinct , so it's incorrect to have 1 then 0... not sure there is nothing bad